# Setting the address of MCP23017 IO Expander when using Multiple

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, raspberry-pi, gpio, io

I'm trying to use the MCP23017 I2C port extender which has 3 addressing pins to be externally biased to set the I2C device address.

How should I connect the 3 addressing pins to select the I2C address that I want? I was not able to identify a table mapping the biasing to the I2C address in its [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf).

Also, should I be biasing by connecting some address pins to GND, some to 5V of my Raspberry? Diagram below show show I am currently wiring up three MCP23017 to a single Raspberry 3. Does the wiring look ok?

[**[Link to clearer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD12R.png)**]

[image]

Comment: table 1-1 and figure 3-6 in the datasheet

Comment: you can iterate I2C devices, so just try a combo and scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure 3.4 (Page 15 of the datasheet shows the device addressing), and yes A0,1,2 are digital inputs, 0 or 5V depending should be fine.

Read the device errata I recall being being some shenanigans, but that may have been only the SPI variant.

Comment: Thank you! Am I right to say that in the schematic in the question, the bottom most MCP23017 has a slave address of `0x20`, and the top most MCP23017 has a slave address of `0x22`?

Comment: In 7 bit format, yes.